# Why isn't my site redirecting to https from http?

Tags: redirect, https

Good day, i have redirected my site using .htaccess but my http://www.example.com would not load unless i manually add the https:// to it.

Here is what my .htaccess looks like;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.feathersignature.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

<IfModule php5_module>
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_value post_max_size 50M
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_value post_max_size 50M
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Please what can  do to properly redirect my site? I am a new developer and i want to learn. Thank you